# Raspberry Pi to Ardunio Pro Micro Serial connections

Tags: arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi, circuit

Im connecting a RPi to a Ardunio Pro Micro board via the serial Tx/Rx pins.
This is the first time im building circuits like this so im a little unsure about volts and resistors and stuff.

I am following a picture example from http://blog.oscarliang.net/ctt/uploads/2013/05/arduino-raspberry-pi-serial-connect-schematics.jpg for the resistor set up however this is for a Ardunio Uno and not the Pro Micro.
Also people keep talking about plugging in the USB or not.
Im not connecting the 3.3v or 5v GPIO pins from the Pi and would like to get power from the USB on the Ardunio and the Pi from the micro USB power socket.

So i just want to clarify before i fry the boards that the resistors and circuits in the picture will still work on the Ardunio Pro Micro (moving the pins to their correct place on that board)

Comment: As @Andreas Behrend said, the resistors are fine. Personally I'd increase them by a 10 factor (16k and 33k), but that's just a personal opinion. On the other channel you can have problems (Atmega's Vih is 0.7*Vcc, which is 3.5V) but I don't think you would. If you have problems, just put a buffer. As for the power, you can take the 5V from the raspberry and plug it to the 5V on the arduino. Ths way they will share the power (and you will need just to plug something in the raspberry micro usb socket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the Arduino Pro Micro operates at a voltage level of 5V like the Uno, it's serial connection also uses 5V. This means the voltage divider circuit shown in your link works also for the Pro Micro.

If you want you can do the math on your own:
Vout = (R2/(R1+R2)) * Vin
Vout is the input voltage at the Rx pin of the RPi
Vin is the output voltage of the Arduino at his Tx pin
R1 is the resistor near to the Arduinos Tx pin (1600 Ohm)
R2 is the resistor near to the RPis Rx pin (3300 Ohm)

I hope this helps :)